# Extending Java Iterable to support direction iteration direction?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I am implementing a class that implements the [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

I'm looking for a way I can have the iterator() method return an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) that is moving forward (starting from 0 index), or backward (starting from last index).

I don't need any other operations outside the ones available in [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

I'm not sure the best design for this - perhaps a constructor parameter that changes the underlying Iterator that is returned?

Or, is there some other pattern to accomplish it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

Comment: @JBNizet I wanted to avoid having to implement all the methods in ListIterator.

Comment: So you want the returned Iterator to have a`previous() ` method, essentially?

Comment: @JBNizet I see now that many of the methods are optional to support.  I will consider ListIterator, thanks.

Comment: All the operations that don't consist in iterating forward or backward are optional, so you may avoid to implement them.

Comment: Take a look at `List.listIterator()`. It allows traversing in both directions.